# Define a matrix module in OCaml

Tags: module, matrix, ocaml

I would like to build a general matrix module, which includes such general operations as length, width, size, read_element, write_element, etc. As a matrix could be defined with several types: `element array array`, `element list list` or with `map`, the advantage of this module is to handle the details of the type of matrix inside it, and do not bother on the level where the module is called. At the moment, I think of something as follows:

```
module type A_TYPE =
  sig
    type t
  end;;

module matrix =
  functor (Elt: A_TYPE) 
  struct
    type element = Elt.t
    type t = element array array 
      (* `element list list` if I want a matrix to be a list of a list *)

    let length (m: t) : int =
       Array.length a
      (* `List.length a` if t = element list list *)

    ... ...

  end
```

So from outside, one can write:

```
module MyInt = struct type t = int end
module MatInt = Matrix(MyInt)
module MyFloat = struct type t = float end
module MatFloat = Matrix(MyFloat)

let m = MatInt.make 3 4 0
let n = MatFloat.make 3 4 0.2
```

My questions are:

1) I have to define first a module `MyInt`, then put it into the functor to create `MatInt`... I found it redundant... Is there a way to instantiate directly a matrix module whose elements have `int` as type?

2) Considering what is written in `(* ... *)`, is there a way to implement the matrix module such that it handles at same time the different possibilities of type of a matrix? maybe with a pattern-matching?

Hope my questions are clear, could anyone help?

Comment: I feel like you're reinventing the wheel. Take a look at Polka http://pop-art.inrialpes.fr/~bjeannet/newpolka/html/polka_72.html#SEC97

Comment: @pad: do you have any idea of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865283/using-matrix-module-of-polka-in-ocaml)? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Polka. I mention it here because its module signature perfectly matches your requirements.

Comment: Actually I just learned that Matrix module does not exist anymore in Polka...

Comment: Really? Where do you get that information?

Comment: From one developer of Polka :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for question #1: you don't have to define a MyInt module, you could cut out that step by doing:

```
 module MatInt = Matrix(struct type t = int end)
```